# Create a wrapper div within field groups on node displays

Tags: entities

For ease of formatting I would like to add an inner wrapper div inside of field groups displaying on content nodes and node forms. I'm using the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module to display groups in div format.

Currently it's this:

```
<div class="field-group-format group_user field-group-div group-user required-fields  speed-fast effect-none">
…
</div>
```

Would like to output this:

```
<div class="field-group-format group_user field-group-div group-user required-fields  speed-fast effect-none">
<div class="inner">
 … 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the theme_preprocess_node hook in your custom theme and add your inner div using the #prefix and #suffix of the fieldgroup.
It should be in $variables['content']['name_of_the_fieldgorup']['#prefix'] .

Answer (score 2):

Try [hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter()](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/field_group/field_group.api.php/function/hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter/7) since node content solution seems not longer working.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter().
 * Adds additional wrappers
 */
function [your_theme_or_module_name]_field_group_build_pre_render_alter(&$element) {
  if (!empty($element['group_tabs'])) {
    $element['group_tabs']['#prefix'] = '<div class="field-group-container">';
    $element['group_tabs']['#prefix'] .= '<div class="field-group-row">';
    $element['group_tabs']['#suffix'] .= '</div></div>';
  }
}
```

Check [Field group for developers](https://www.drupal.org/node/1017962) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to handle this is to use Views Display Modes from [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds).