# field_groups - adding an inner div wrapper programatically

Tags: 7, entities

I have some older code that used [this method](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/81988/48285) to add an inner div containing inline style.

Much like the linked question above. I am using hook_preprocess_node to attempt this.

However, the $variables['content'] array no longer seems to contain the groups in it and I'm not sure exactly what's changed. I haven't managed to find much else on this in the issue queue and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that this has changed and I can't really find any posts relating to it.

I'm going to update my code to use [hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter()](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/field_group/field_group.api.php/function/hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter/7) as an alternative.